Group of people hangs out in some underground place (entrance: cap in the ground)
I watched this movie a long time ago, so excuse me if I'm not very exact. 
It was about 4-6 people being in this underground thing. The entrance to this underground house, living place, whatever (I have no idea what to call it) was this cap in the ground. I don't remember much of it, but I remember that they at some point did drugs and drank alcohol down there, but that was later in the movie.
It wasn't a horror movie, as far as I recall.
I know it isn't much, but does anyone have a clue about which movie this might be?


Could it be "The Hole (2001)"?
Can't make out much from your description, but this movie fits your bill. Up to a point.

Four teenagers at a British private school secretly uncover and
  explore the depths of a sealed underground hole created decades ago as
  a possible bomb shelter.


Do any of those faces look familiar? The movie does show the characters drinking and partying in the bunker (watch those scenes in the trailer). But there's no drug use as far as I can recall, and this page confirms it. Also, as the story progresses, it unravels into a psychological thriller with a fair bit of blood (read murder).
You can read more about the plot here. Watch the trailer and/or the full movie.

Can you also update the post with the source of the images?

@Annjawn The first one is a movie poster, easily available via Google. And it's one of the many versions out there. I simply chose the one with better typography :-) The still from the movie? A simple image search will give you dozens of sources i.e. http://tinyurl.com/ohfvg23

Sometimes, it's a good idea to post where the images are originally hosted and always safer to use images from wiki commons. Just my 2 cents.

Fair enough, and I have seen postings out here which point out the source of the pics used. So if there is a growing interest in figuring out where the pics I use originate from, I'll keep your suggestion in mind :-) P.S. Just kidding about the "growing interest" bit!
